# Using a For Loop to multiply variables by numbers in a matrix

Tags: r

This should be relatively simple but I am new to R and cannot quite figure this out.

I will illustrate what I am trying to do.

I have the following:

```
names <- c("A","B","C")
values <- c(3,6,9)
values2 <- c(5,10,15)
y <- c("2019")
r <- c("1")
t <- c("Team A", "Team B", "Team C")
mgn <- c(33, 56, 63)
df1 <- data.frame(names,y,r,t,values,values2,mgn)
```

I also have a matrix:

```
numbers <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
```

I am trying to loop through each of the `values` and `values2` in my `df1` and multiply these by the values in my `numbers` matrix like so:

```
3 x 1 = 3
5 x 4 = 20

6 x 2 = 12
10 x 5 = 50

9 x 3 = 27
15 x 6 = 90
```

I would then like to print each of these values like:

```
    values    values2
[1] 3          20
[2] 12         50
[3] 18         90
```

I tried the following (just for the first `values` col):

```
for(col in 1:ncol(numbers)){ 
    df1$values %*% numbers[col]
    print(df1$values)
  }
```

But this is the ouput I get:

```
[1] 3 6 9
[1]  6 12 18
[1]  6 12 18
[1] 12 24 36
[1] 12 24 36
[1] 24 48 72
```

I then would like to repeat the process, so that the next row of values and values2 is multiplied by the first row again in numbers (2 and 5) so that:

```
3 x 2 = 6
5 x 5 = 25
```

and so on, until all the combinations are calculated.

This would give me the output like so:

```
3 x 1 = 3
5 x 4 = 20

6 x 1 = 6
10 x 4 = 40

9 x 1 = 9
15 x 4 = 60
```

Then it should go to the next line of values and values2 and repeat:

```
3 x 2 = 6
5 x 5 = 25

6 x 2 = 12
10 x 5 = 50

9 x 2 = 18
15 x 5 = 75
```

And finally the last line:

```
3 x 3 = 9
5 x 6 = 30

6 x 3 = 18
10 x 6 = 60

9 x 3 = 27
15 x 6 = 90
```

Finally, I would like to loop through each of these, add them together like:

```
sumvalues = values + values2
```

create a total column like:

```
df1%>%group_by(y, r, t)%>%dplyr::mutate(total=sum(sumvalues)
```

then obtain the pearson correlation for each by:

```
cor(mgn, sumvalues, method = "pearson")
```

So I can have the output like so:

```
     sumvalues    total    mgn    pearson
[1] 
[2]
[3]
```

Comment: Assuming your `numbers` is `numbers <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 3, ncol = 2)`. You can do : `df1[-1] * numbers`

Comment: @RonakShah yes it is. I have amended my matrix in my post. However this returns the same 3 numbers a total of 6 times?

Comment: Please clarify the expected output in regards to 'all the combinations are calculated' as this isn't clear.

Comment: @27ϕ9 - I have edited my post above to explain this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first output can be reached by :

```
df1[-1] * numbers

#  values values2
#1      3      20
#2     12      50
#3     27      90
```

To get all possible combinations you can use `apply` with `sweep` :

```
apply(numbers, 1, function(x) sweep(df1[-1], 2, x, `*`))

#[[1]]
#  values values2
#1      3      20
#2      6      40
#3      9      60

#[[2]]
#  values values2
#1      6      25
#2     12      50
#3     18      75

#[[3]]
#  values values2
#1      9      30
#2     18      60
#3     27      90
```

Comment: this is great and exactly what I need. Is there a way to complete the final piece of the task as I have edited in my post above?

Comment: Please don't change/extend the question after it has been answered if it is not related to original question. Can you add it as a new question instead?

Comment: ok will do I apologize. I am new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it:

```
#### make the two objects to have the same dimensions:
df2<-df1[ ,c(2:3)]

#### multiply and create new object:
new<-df2*numbers

#### if you want to return the first column to df1:
df3<-cbind(df1[1],x)
print(df3)
```